# Save Text With Image Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I need to save images with corresponding text data. My first idea was to just save the image as Base64 as text in a normal sql database, but I read that images should only be transported as base64, not stored - so I started looking into Azure Blob Storage which stores images and such perfectly. The problem is: *I don't know how to pair an image with a small dataset*. Should I store an additional textfile, also how do I pair ONE image with ONE dataset? Multiple containers ?? Every bit of help is obviously needed :)

Comment: While there's no single "right" answer, consider using a queryable database (MySQL, SQL Database, Cosmos DB, etc) to store your searchable text & metadata, along with a property containing the URI of a blob. Very common pattern, but the specifics on how you do this are really up to you (which database to choose, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

If it's only small amounts of metadata you want to set, why not use Blob User-defined metadata? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/setting-and-retrieving-properties-and-metadata-for-blob-resources

Here are examples of how to do this using the .NET SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-properties-metadata